# How to call child component method in parent component react function components?

Tags: reactjs

I write all functional components, now I want to call a child component method in parent component. is it possible or not? If yes, Please give me some direction to do it.Thanks in advance.

```
import React, { useRef } from 'react';
import ChildOne from './child_one'
import ChildTwo  from './child_two'

function ParentComponent(props) {

  const childRef = useRef();

  const onTabChange = (e,{activeIndex})=> {
    console.log(childRef)
  }

  let panes = [
   {menuItem: 'ChildOne', render: () => <Tab.Pane  attached={false}> 
     <ChildOne ref={childRef}/></Tab.Pane>},
   {menuItem: 'ChildTwo', render: () => <Tab.Pane attached={false}> 
     <ChildTwo/> </Tab.Pane>},
  ]

  return(

   <Tab menu={{secondary:true, pointing:true}} panes={panes} 
    onTabChange={onTabChange}/>
 )
}
export default ParentComponent;
```

child 1

```
import React, { forwardRef, useImperativeHandle } from 'react';

export default function Child1Component forwardRef((data,ref) => {

updateData = () =>{
    console.log(update data)
}


ref={updateData}
return(
    <h1>Child one</h1>
)
})
```

child2

```
import React from 'react'
export default function Child2Component (data) => {return(<h1>Child Two</h1>)}
```

I tried with above code, but getting getAlert not a function.

Comment: Please include what you've tried in the question

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Call child method from parent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37949981/call-child-method-from-parent)

Comment: Without seeing any code I'm inclined to say no. If the function belongs to the child then generally only the child component, or descendants of the child the function is passed to, can call it. Children can invoke functions passed to them as props. Please include a [Minimal, Complete, and Reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) example of your code.

Comment: I am asking for function components, but here only class component example and reference, I didn't understand. give me solution in functional components. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use refs to do that.
https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html

Check out this example:
https://codesandbox.io/s/exposing-functions-through-ref-cxx6t

Comment: I am getting ref is null.

Comment: did you check my code sandbox example?
you should mutate the ref in the child component

Comment: I want to call childone component method in tabChange function in parent component.

Comment: Yeah, I checked it, in your child component shows ref object, but in my child component shows null.

Comment: try in the child component to add: ref = {updateData}

Comment: I don't see it in the code. what are you doing with useimperativehandling?

Comment: I find my mistake, I am using redux connect. so, It's not working, can you help to me to fix it?

Comment: the fourth parameter of connect is options.

function connect(mapStateToProps?, mapDispatchToProps?, mergeProps?, options?).

in which you can forward a ref

{
  context?: Object,
  pure?: boolean,
  areStatesEqual?: Function,
  areOwnPropsEqual?: Function,
  areStatePropsEqual?: Function,
  areMergedPropsEqual?: Function,
  forwardRef?: boolean,
}

you can look at https://react-redux.js.org/api/connect#options-object
tell me if you need an example

Comment: please give me an example?

Comment: greay! happy to help